# Replace XML payload or json payload with empty value

Tags: java, json, xml, string, jackson

I need to remove unwanted logs at higher environment for the logger optimization so got the requirements to remove json or XML payload from string.

```java
String jsonString= "This is jsonstring:{\"name\":\"xyz",\"address\":\"pqr\"}";

String xmlString= "This is xmlString not able to convert in code format of XML content:

<customer>John Smith</customer>";
```

Tried with json using Jackson library seems working but I need to integrate in such a way that by checking condition like XML or json and then can remove payload and set empty values. Looking forward your help.

```java
int i= str.indexOf("{");

JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(str.substring(i));

ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode)jsonNode;

object.removeAll();
```

Comment: With object.removeAll() you remove the whole object, not just the values. So what is the goal? To completely remove the XML and JSON data? Then I would change something in the logging.

Comment: The goal is to remove completely based on the response either XML or json.

Comment: Can someone help on this how to remove complete XML or json payload. I have spent more than a day but not yet achieved the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your two examples, it should look like this:

```php
static String cleanUpLogItem(String logItem) {
    return logItem.substring(0, logItem.indexOf(":")).trim();
}
```

Test:

```java
public class FooBarTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("dataProvider")
    void test_cleanUpLogItem(String logItem, String expected) {
        assertEquals(expected, cleanUpLogItem(logItem));
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> dataProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(
                        "This is jsonstring:{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"address\":\"pqr\"}",
                        "This is jsonstring"
                ),
                Arguments.of(
                        "This is xmlString not able to convert in code format of XML content: <customer>John Smith</customer>",
                        "This is xmlString not able to convert in code format of XML content"
                )
    }
}
```